# Finding edges of road using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am interested in finding the edges of the road. The output image should have only edges marked.
Here is one of my input image:

[image]

But the edges in output are either distorted or have lot of noise.
Here is its output:

[image: output]

I have tried applying watershed algorithm, but it does not detect the roads properly.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('road2.jpg',0)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)
#Removing noise from image
blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
#finding edges using edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 100 ,200)


laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(edges, cv2.CV_8UC1)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(laplacian,cv2.CV_8UC1, 0, 1, ksize=5)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sobely,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

frame = cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('window',frame)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should do inoder to mark only the edges. I want only the edges in the output beacuse I would later need these edges to find the middle lane of the road.

Comment: If this was easy you'd already be seating in a googlecar...

Comment: But road detection is definitely possible implemented by many people.

Comment: And why should this question receive negative votes ?

Comment: because it is not easily answerable so off-topic, fyi I also flagged as "too broad". While definitely possible (to some extent), there is no 5 line answer to the problem.

Comment: Nor was I expecting a 5 line answer.     Most of answers in stackoverflow are more than '5 lines'

Comment: Ok, what I mean is there is no clear cut answer. This is still an active research topic challenging the best researchers in academia and global companies like google. This is just like asking how to land automatically a spaceX rocket...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Lep.jpg). Not perfect, but best I could do. Idea taken from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/)

The code works for this image on the assumption that:

If there are no cars on the road, then the two markings(left and right), will meet at a vanishing point on the horizon and form a triangle. So, I keep only the largest contour that can be approximated by a triangle.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('road2.jpg',0)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)
#Removing noise from image
blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
#finding edges using edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 100 ,200)


laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(edges, cv2.CV_8UC1)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(laplacian,cv2.CV_8UC1, 0, 1, ksize=5)

# Do a dilation and erosion to accentuate the triangle shape
dilated = cv2.dilate(sobely,kernel,iterations = 1)
erosion = cv2.erode(dilated,kernel,iterations = 1)

im2, contours, hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(erosion,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#keep 10 largest contours
cnts = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
screenCnt = None

for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    # if our approximated contour has three points, then
    # it must be the road markings
    if len(approx) == 3:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
cv2.drawContours(img, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Road markings", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: @parikshit if this helped you, then please accept the solution.